# dotnet pack targeting multiple frameworks

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core

I have a dotnet core project that targets 2 frameworks :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0;net45</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

using `dotnet build -c Release -f net45|netcoreapp1.0` I can build my class library for the desired framewok. 
But I can't found how to do the same with the `dotnet-pack` command. I fails with the followin error :

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(84,5): error : Cannot infer TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion from TargetFramework='netcoreapp1.0'. They must be specified explicitly. [C:\Users\olduh\sly\sly\sly\sly.csproj]
```

Is there a way to multi target framework when building nuget package ?

thanks for your answers,

Olivier

Comment: Turns out the error message is misleading, i opened a PR to fix that it is being cut off https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1173

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For multi-targeting, use the plural `TargetFrameworks` property to provide a list of frameworks. `TargetFramework`(singular) only accepts a single framework. If you fix the missing `s` on the property name, `dotnet pack -c Release` should work as expected - without the need to specify any framework parameter.

You probably did not update the property when adding an additional framework. By specifying the `-f` option, you have overwritten this property to make it work, but i guess that a `dotnet build` will fail with the same error.

Comment: Thanks Martin, It does the job.